Unable to Boot Windows After Failed GRUB Installation While Installing Ubuntu on HP Notebook
I'm facing an issue while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows using a live USB. Here's the context:
Current State:
Windows had 4 partitions:
Local C: ~90-100 GB used (mostly program files), only 3-8 GB free.
Local E: Had some program files and personal data (backed up personal data).
Local F:  ( had like upto 400 gb) Mostly personal files, but after clearing it, it still showed ~10 GB used.
System Reserved: ~400-500 MB.
I tried installing Ubuntu and partitioned the disk as follows:
[ I used the local f space of space upto 389-400 gb which i deleted mainly for Ubuntu
30 GB for / (root).
7 GB for swap.
100 GB for /home.
~200 GB for EFI  (since it was asking for an EFI partition idk why )
During installation, the GRUB installation failed and installation crashed , and now I can't boot into Windows
How can I recover my Windows bootloader or at least boot back into Windows?
I’m really hoping someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks for taking the time to read this!

This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. If it was askiing for another, then you have an issue with your existing one. Was Windows bitlocker on? or Windows fast startup? Or did it need chkdsk from Windows or dosfsck from Ubuntu? ESP should only be 100MB to 600MB. UEFI boot files for both Windows & Ubuntu will fit into 100MB, but for future use, if space available larger size suggested.
